# VB/C# - Replace String

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, linq, replace

How can I replace the first and the last occurence of a String by a string in VB or C#?

Lets say the String looks like this:

```
Hello/This/is/awesome/stuff/produced/by/me
```

And after replacing should look like this:

```
Hello|||This/is/awesome/stuff/produced/by|||me
```

Can someone show me whats the fastest way doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your question, you can have two functions: One for each replace. This is for the first replace.

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(string str, string search, string newText)
{
       int ind = str.IndexOf(search);
       if (ind < 0)
       {
           return str;
       }
       return str.Substring(0, ind) + newText + str.Substring(ind + search.Length);
}
```

This is for the second replace:

```
public static string ReplaceLast(string str, string search, string newText)
{
    int ind = str.LastIndexOf(search);
    if (ind < 0)
    {
        return str;
    }
    return str.Substring(0, ind) + newText + str.Substring(ind + search.Length);
}
```

Now you use them like this:

```
var str = @"Hello/This/is/awesome/stuff/produced/by/me";
var res = ReplaceFirst(str, "/", "|||");
res = ReplaceLast(res, "/", "|||");
```

Comment: @nexno Glad I could help! Please try to mark the answers you choose as accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

I like this approach:

```
var texts = text.Split(new [] { '/' });
var result = string.Join("|||", new []
{
    texts.First(),
    string.Join(@"/", texts.Skip(1).Take(texts.Length - 2)),
    texts.Last(),
});
```

To me, this is rather explicit in how it works.

Comment: Thank you, I also converted this to vb.net:

Comment: `Dim texts = text.Split(New () {"/"C})
Dim result = String.Join("|||", New () {texts.First(), String.Join("/", texts.Skip(1).Take(texts.Length - 2)), texts.Last()})`